# Vue Cli 3 exclude typescript file from being injected in index.html

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I created a project typescript project with the Vue Cli.

**I want to have a separated `commands.html` file that should contain the javascript code from a `commands.ts` file.**

I put the `commands.html` file in the `public` folder, so it is copied to the `dist` folder when building the project.

The `commands.ts` file is in the root folder (in the same folder in that the `public`, `src`, `node_modules`, etc folders are).

Webpack should do the following:

1. Minify the `commands.html` file (like it is minifying the `index.html`)
2. Compile the `commands.ts` file to JavaScript
3. Put the generated JavaScript file to the `dist/js` folder
4. Put a script tag in the `commands.html` file that points to the generated JavaScript file

**I tried the following:**

I installed `html-webpack-plugin`

I created a `vue.config.js` file with the following code:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      commands: './commands.ts',
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'commands.html',
        template: './public/commands.html',
        chunks: ['commands'],
        minify: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

That is doing everything correctly, but it also creates a script tag in the `index.html` file that points to the generated JavaScript file. I think the default Webpack config of Vue is compiling the `commands.ts` in the bundle that is injected in the `index.html` file. How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: have you tried the "files" option as used in the examples here:
https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options
You can specify which JS  files or whatever files, may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    entry: {
      functionFile: './functionFile.ts',
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'functionFile.html',
        template: './public/functionFile.html',
        chunks: ['functionFile'],
        minify: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
    devServer: {
      https: true,
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
      .tap((args) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        args[0].excludeChunks = ['functionFile'];
        return args;
      });
  },
};
```